# Внешние ключи MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Хотелось бы узнать у более опытных пользователей, как поступить? Вот у меня есть табличка **Users**, и мне требуется создать таблицу **Projects**, но чтобы в таблицу вносился *ID* пользователя, который имеет значение первичного ключа, который находится в таблице **Users**.

Этим хочу реализовать авторство пользователя над каждым проектом.

Но как поступить? Использовать в таблице **Projects** *foreign key*, ссылающийся на *ID* пользователя. Или просто брать *ID* из сессии, и при создании проекта вносить его в таблицу в месте с остальными данными?

Comment: какая разница откуда вы его и как возьмете, если суть от этого никак не меняется?

Comment: первое без второго все равно невозможно. так что второе в любом случае обязательно, а первое по желанию

Comment: вопрос вида "хочу чаю с сахаром. Мне брать сахар из  банки, или ложкой? если я все равно его кину в чашку"

Comment: *как поступить? Использовать в таблице Projects foreign key, ссылающийся на ID пользователя* Зависит от того, допускают ли бизнес-процессы существование проекта с двумя и более кураторами (пусть и временно и/или в виде исключения). Если нет - то альтернативы созданию FK не существует, вернее такой альтернативой является потенция присутствия в БД несогласованных данных, которые к тому же некоторое время не будут обнаружены...

Comment: Думаю автор вопроса не понимает суть внешних ключей. Я довольно часто тут наблюдаю такое. Отсюда и родился такой странный вопрос. Отвечаю: раз пользователь в users и на него надо сослаться из таблицы проектов - то да, foreign обязателен. Но foreign это все лишь декларация для БД, что поля связаны и что нельзя вставить в проекты запись с не существующим пользователем. БД автоматически вести значение в этом поле не будет. И вам все равно надо явно вносить нужное значение из сессии когда редактируется запись проекта

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ответ. Я понял. Получается, для логичной и корректной работы следует все два варианта делать?

Comment: @Вячеслав Да. Foreign просто дополнительная защита. Если вы в коде ошибетесь и попробуете записать в проект в поле пользователь что то другое, то MySQL вам этого не даст сделать и выдаст ошибку. Так же он не позволит вам скажем удалить пользователя, если у него есть проекты (иначе получится что ссылка ведет вникуда). Ну либо если на foreign поставить опцию on delete cascade (чего я бы в данном случае не делал) то MySQL при удалении пользователя автоматически удалит все его проекты. И да, делать надо и то и другое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, желательно создать `foreign key`. Примерно так вы должны создать таблицу:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `project` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
)
```

Вы можете, например, сказать базе данных удалять проект, если из базы данных будет удален пользователь:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `project` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
)
ALTER TABLE `project`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Но Вы сможете использовать `JOIN` и без `FK`.

```sql
SELECT `project`.*, `user`.`name` from `project`
    LEFT JOIN `user` ON `user`.`id` = `project`.`user_id`
```

Создавать ключи рекомендуется потому что это может быть удобно для действий при обновлении или удалении пользователя. Кроме того, база данных не даст Вам создать проект с неверным ID пользователя, если вы не хотите привязывать проект к какому либо пользователю вы можете установить `NULL` если в данном поле разрешено данное значение. А так же некоторые менеджеры баз данных начинают более внятно выражаться в своем интерфейсе. Например `HeidiSQL` начинает показывать еще и имя в своей таблице:

[image: HeidiSQL показывает имя по id]

Кроме того, говорят, что это увеличивает скорость поиска в базе данных, когда существует явный ключ, база данных будет сразу же знать, где ей искать данные. Хотя я не могу за это ручаться, так как подтверждений этому я не видел.